# Vector of Any to Shapeless HList

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scalaz, shapeless

Is there a way to convert a vector of type Any to Shapeless HList (productelement)

```
val frame = Vector(Vector(1,"a","b",false),Vector(2,"y","z",false),Vector(3,"p","q",true))

frame.map(_.hlisted) or frame.map(_.productElements)
```

I am attempting to convert to the following structure

```
List[Int :: String :: String :: Boolean :: HNil](1 :: a :: b :: false :: HNil, 2 :: y :: z :: false :: HNil, 3 :: p :: q :: true :: HNil)
```

Based on Shapless Migration guide, it's possible with Typed Tuples

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Migration-guide:-shapeless-1.2.4-to-2.0.0#productelements-is-the-new-name-for-hlisted

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.product._  // New import

scala> (23, "foo", true).productElements // was '.hlisted'
res0: Int :: String :: HNil = 23 :: foo :: true :: HNil
```

Is this possible with untyped Vectors or perhaps a vector -> Typed Tuples -> HList ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you have to specify the types, and since this is a cast that can fail at runtime, you'll get the results wrapped in `Option`:

```
import shapeless._, syntax.std.traversable._

val hlists = frame.map(_.toHList[Int :: String :: String :: Boolean :: HNil])
```

Now `hlists` has type `Vector[Option[Int :: String :: String :: Boolean :: HNil]]`, and in this case specifically all of the conversions are successful, so they're all wrapped in `Some`.

Comment: Is there a way to infer types?
The reason to ask is that I am attempting to map sql query results to HList
 
SQL query results are based on the selection criteria i.e.

`select a,b,c from table
select * from table
select b,c from table
`

The results in these cases might vary and the current resultrow is represented as a 

`Vector(Vector(x,x,x..), Vector(x,x,x,))`